# JWT blacklisting table and performance issues consideration

Tags: jwt

I'm currently have a RESTful backend with Spring. Since RESTful is stateless, i've decided to go with JWT since throughout my research that's what everyone recommendation (at least for REST-based app).

Considering the normal flow of authentication phase:

```
Frontend                                                      Backend
--- Login flow (refresh token request flow). ---

Login details                               ->        Verify login info
                                                      |
                                                      v
Save the refresh token                      <-        Generate JWT refresh token

--- Access token request flow. ---

Request new access token                    ->        Generate a new Access token
                                                      |
                                                      v
Save the access token                       <-        Give back to user
(Repeat when the access token expires)

--- Logout flow ---

Call JWT token invalidating API             ->        Add a refresh token and access token's hashes 
                                                      to blacklist table.
                                                      |
                                                      v
Erase JWT access token and refresh token    <-        Return result to user.
from storage
```

Now look at the following above flow, we'll need a table for storing blacklisted JWT token for both access token and refresh token.
Since we don't want user to re-login frequently, refresh token may have validity for years.

So, my question is: Is malicious user able to attack a system by logout and re-login multiple times that leads to a big refresh token blacklist table (which may degrades the system performance even below stateful authentication).

Is such attack surface exists ? If yes, how'll we mitigate it ?

- I'm thinking about reusing refresh token but I don't think that'll be
  a good idea, at least for security purposes.
- Or maybe using rate-limiting for login request, but I think it's a
  bit weird considering that it's normal operation and user may legitimately perform many re-authentication request.
- Or maybe using CAPTCHA for authentication but is it enough ? Legitimate user may re-authenticate many times and table might got very big.

The database I'm using is SQL (PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 0):

So what I've found out that it has much more to be done with authentication & authorization than I imagined before.
Because of that, I ended up integrating external SSO provider to manage all the authentication part for me (keycloak specifically).